# How does the Warpriest's major Travel Blessing interact with Aspect of War?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, class-feature, divine

I'm curious about how two different [Warpriest](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/classes/hybrid-classes/warpriest) class features interact with each other. The features in question are Aspect of War and the major Travel Blessing. To what extent do these two features combined result in and is there a way to further increase the distance?

Avatar of War (emphasis mine):

> At 20th level, the warpriest can channel an aspect of war, growing in power and martial ability. Once per day as a swift action, a warpriest can treat his level as his base attack bonus, gains DR 10/—, and can move at his full speed regardless of the armor he is wearing or his encumbrance. In addition, **the blessings he calls upon don't count against his daily limit during this time**. This ability lasts for 1 minute.

Blessings class feature (only the section that is relevant to this question):

> A warpriest can call upon the power of his blessings a number of times per day (in any combination) equal to 3 + 1/2 his warpriest level (to a maximum of 13 times per day at 20th level). Each time he calls upon any one of his blessings, it counts against his daily limit.

Travel Blessing (emphasis mine):

> Dimensional Hop (major): At 10th level, you can teleport up to 20 feet as a move action. **You can increase this distance by expending another use of your blessing—each use spent grants an additional 20 feet**. You must have line of sight to your destination. This teleportation doesn't provoke attacks of opportunity. You can bring other willing creatures with you, but each such creature requires expending one additional use of your blessing, regardless of the distance traveled. (**For example, transporting yourself 40 feet costs 2 uses of your blessing**, and transporting an additional person this distance costs 1 more use.)

This *seems* to say that a level 20 Warpriest can, if he so chooses for whatever reason, use double moves every round to teleport 260 feet up to 12 times in a single minute.

Is this correct? And are there any other ways to increase the distance?

Comment: I think the math says the theoretical maximum distance teleported is **280 ft.** because you get to include the initial 20 ft. from being able to use the ability at all in the first place, but I'm pretty sure that doesn't count as a way to increase the distance. `:-)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### It's debatable, even in RAW

The one side of the argument is clear, you don't spend blessings, so you extend all you want (within the limits given by the blessing).

However, I can see a way of reading this as to require you to actually spend the additional blessings per day even in Avatar form. This is based on the small difference in text, namely between

> the **blessings he calls upon** don't count against his daily limit during this time.

and

> You can increase this distance by **expending another use of your blessing**—each use spent grants an additional 20 feet.

(all emphasis mine). Extending the range of Travel blessing does not constitute "calling upon a blessing", that's just the initial 20ft. hop. The extension does not "use" blessings per day, they are just removed from your account.

If this looks a bit nitpicky and far-fetched to you, that's because it is.

---

#### Allowing it is perfectly fine

That said, I don't think a RAW discussion is really worth it in this case. We're looking at a 20th level character using his 1/day capstone ability to gain good tactical range movement capabilities for 1 minute. At his best, the character can teleport the entire party anywhere within line of sight, which can lead to good tactical options (full-party move-action teleportation is nice), but it's in no way overpowered, or even among the better abilities available to characters at 20th level.

Even without the limit of (not) spending 13 blessings per use at most that you have set in the question (which is debatable as well), long-range travel à la mountaintop to mountaintop is still superseded by "real" teleportation spells, which are readily available that that level (and long before).